# Can you use cached_property inside a "Static" class method

Tags: python, oop

I have this wonder about how python looks at classmethods and cached_properties.
To depict my question here is some code

```py
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def some_command(cls) -> int:
        result = cls.slow_but_always_the_same_result_calculation()  # :)
        ...

    @cached_property
    def slow_but_always_the_same_result_calculation(self):
        ...  # Do the slow calculation
        return result
```

With the setup from above what is going to happen if I use MyClass:

```py
#  First case
import MyClass
MyClass.some_command()
```

```py
#  Second case
import MyClass
my_class_instance = MyClass()
my_class_instance.some_command()
```

I would love to know whether the first case is possible - **Using the cached_property with "Static" class method calling? What is the value of result in some_command when its called with "Static" class method calling?**

Comment: Your code inside `some_command()` doesn't make sense. It's impossible to call `slow_but_always_the_same_result_calculation()` from it without creating an instance of `MyClass` to operate on.

Comment: That is the essence of my question. Is it possible to use cached_propery inside a classmethod?

Comment: Even if the `slow_but_always_the_same_result_calculation()` function wasn't cached, you wouldn't be able to call it from your `some_command()` classmethod.

Comment: But the idea here is that this is a property holding the return of that method. Maybe to rephrase the question: can this be calculated and used as a property without the need of a class instance; When is this calculated, what tells python to calculate it?

Comment: If you mark it as a `classmethod` as well then it should work. There's no reason why you can't use multiple decorators on the one function.

Comment: Good, forgive me for being annoying Andrew but in that case what is the order of decorating and does it matter for the purpose of the question?

Comment: You can't call an instance method from a class method without creating an instance to call it on. `cls.slow_but_always_the_same_result_calculation()` will give you an error.

Comment: Can you submit some proof code or docs?

Comment: Here's a code example that shows that what you're trying to do is impossible: https://gist.github.com/MiguelGuthridge/9bc2083a1ea01eb218f6c9fd281984b9